# New to HSQLDB working with Spring Application with JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

I am New to HSQLDB and working with Spring Application with JavaConfig. I want my example to setup a in memory database(HSQLDB) and insert one row.

I think I have my stuff all in order but I don't know where to create the database and the tables.

Below is my main.app code

```
public class MainApp
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(MainApp.class);

    @Autowired
    protected MessageService mService;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);
        HelloWorld helloWorld = context.getBean(HelloWorld.class);

        LOGGER.debug("Message from HelloWorld Bean: " + helloWorld.getMessage());

        /**
         *  I removed the following line... we are now using log4j
         */
        //System.out.println(helloWorld.getMessage());

        helloWorld.setMessage("I am in Staten Island, New York");

        /**
         *  I removed the following line... we are now using log4j
         */
        //System.out.println(helloWorld.getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug("Message from HelloWorld Bean: " + helloWorld.getMessage());
    }
```

and here is my DatabaseConfig.class

```
public class DatabaseConfig
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);


    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory()
    {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.xxxx.model"});

        try
        {
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }


        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", env.getProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", env.getProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode"));

        //Audit History flags
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag"));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager()
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        htm.afterPropertiesSet();
        return htm;
    }
```

but I don't know where the database is create and how do I insert my table before my project runs?

**You can download the source code at the following:
https://github.com/JohnathanMarkSmith/HelloSpringJavaBasedJavaConfig/issues/1**

Comment: possible duplicate of [New to HSQLDB working with Spring Application with JavaConfig. I dont see database starting up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240079/new-to-hsqldb-working-with-spring-application-with-javaconfig-i-dont-see-databa)

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before, take a look at [Startup script to create a schema in HSQLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968067/startup-script-to-create-a-schema-in-hsqldb)

Comment: how do I do this with JavaConfig