# New to HSQLDB working with Spring Application with JavaConfig. I dont see database starting up?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I am New to HSQLDB working with Spring Application with JavaConfig. I dont see database starting up?.. I know I must be doing something wrong.

Here is my databaeconfig

```
public class DatabaseConfig
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);


    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).
        addScript("schema.sql").build();

        return db;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource hsqlDataSource()  {

        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();


        try {
            ds.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            ds.setUsername("sa");
            ds.setPassword("");
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ds;



    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory()
    {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(hsqlDataSource());
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.xxx.model"});

        try
        {
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }


        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", env.getProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", env.getProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode"));

        //Audit History flags
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag"));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager()
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        htm.afterPropertiesSet();
        return htm;
    }


}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public class MainApp
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(MainApp.class);

    @Autowired
    protected static MessageService mService;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);
        HelloWorld helloWorld = context.getBean(HelloWorld.class);

        /**
         * Date:   4/26/13 / 9:26 AM
         *
         * Comments:
         *
         *    I added Log4J to the example.
         */

        LOGGER.debug("Message from HelloWorld Bean: " + helloWorld.getMessage());

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessage(helloWorld.getMessage());
        mService.SaveMessage(message);



        helloWorld.setMessage("I am in Staten Island, New York");


        LOGGER.debug("Message from HelloWorld Bean: " + helloWorld.getMessage());
    }
```

Below is the only error I see on the trying to save data to the database... I dont see anything about the database starting on my console

```
Message from HelloWorld Bean: I love New York.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**You can download the source and read about this issue at the following:
https://github.com/JohnathanMarkSmith/HelloSpringJavaBasedJavaConfig/issues/1**

Comment: please don't do `catch (Exception e)  { LOGGER.error(e.getMessage()); }` it makes it really hard to figure out what's gone wrong. `@Bean` methods can just rethrow all exceptions so your try/catch is unnecessary

Comment: possible duplicate of [New to HSQLDB working with Spring Application with JavaConfig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239222/new-to-hsqldb-working-with-spring-application-with-javaconfig)

Comment: no this is a new error.. so I can't post on the same erorr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to annotate DatabaseConfig with the @Component annotation?

Comment: I am now getting a java.sql.SQLException: This function is not supported on the save of the object

Comment: Shouldn't DatabaseConfig be @Configuration not @Component? (Assuming Spring 3 and above)