# Create schema before hbm2ddl

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I want to test my program with an inmemory hsqldb. To create the table I use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`
But I get an exception because the schemas, defined in the entity classes by annotations, are not created before the tables are created. Now I am searching for an opportunity to create the schemas before hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto runs. To remove the schemas is not an opportunity for me, because I need them for my program.

My problem is pretty much the same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968067/startup-script-to-create-a-schema-in-hsqldb). The different is I do not use spring, so the solution does not work for me.

Comment: @kamil I have used hsqldb DB, but switched to H2 so your solution works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `H2` database, you may provide init command to run with jdbc connection url. For example:

```
your.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=create schema IF NOT EXISTS your_schema
```

Unfortunately, the issue on hibernate jira is still unresolved https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5665

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked with javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test:;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=\\;runscript from '~/workspace/project/src/test/resources/sql/createschema.sql'; in the sql i create all my schemas

Answer (score 3):

Since Hibernate 5 there is a cleaner and more db-independent way, which also works with hsqldb. Add this configuration property:

```
hibernate.hbm2dll.create_namespaces=true
```